# Функция форматирования даты

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Изучаю js и передо мной возникла задача создать функцию форматирования даты.

Скажите пожалуйста, насколько грамотным является данное решение?

```js
// Выводим дату в преобразованном виде

function formatDate(date) {

  let day = date.getDate();
  let month = date.getMonth();
  let year = date.getFullYear();

  day < 10 ? day = `0${day}` : day;
  month < 10 ? month = `0${month}` : month;
  year % 100 !== 0 ? year = year.toString().slice(2) : year;

  return `${day}.${month}.${year}`;

};

// Обертка для основной функции

formatDate = defineType(formatDate);

// Определяем тип входных данных и возвращаем новую дату в соответствии с ними

function defineType(f) {

  return function(date) {

    let newDate;

    if (date.toLowerCase) {

      let dateElems = date.split('-');
      newDate = new Date(...dateElems);

    };

    if (typeof date === 'number') {

      newDate = new Date(date * 1000);

    };

    if (Array.isArray(date)) {

      newDate = new Date(...date);

    };

    if (date.getDate) {

      date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
      return f.call(this, date);

    };

    return f.call(this, newDate)

  };

};

console.log(formatDate('2011-10-02')); // 02.10.11
console.log(formatDate(1234567890)); // 14.02.09
console.log(formatDate([2014, 1, 1])); // 01.01.14
console.log(formatDate(new Date(2014, 0, 1))); // 01.01.14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно проще 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

```
   var a = new Date();    
   a.toLocaleDateString({day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: '2-digit'});
```

Comment: Объект опций передается вторым аргументом. Где потеряли первый?

Comment: Но по-моему этот способ не кроссбразерный? Старые верисии IE поддерживают его

Comment: @AlexanderK, IE много чего не поддерживает, в том числе и шаблонные строки